# Python - resultado incorrecto con isin()

Tags: python

Tengo actualmente un código con un dataframe y una lista, donde quiero comparar si los elementos de la lista coinciden con los de una columna del dataframe. En caso afirmativo, quiero quedarme con la fila completa del dataframe.
Así son el df y la lista

```
print(approval_polls.head(5))

 start_date    end_date         pollster    sponsor  sample_size population  \
0  2020-02-02  2020-02-04           YouGov  Economist       1500.0          a   
1  2020-02-02  2020-02-04           YouGov  Economist        376.0          a   
2  2020-02-02  2020-02-04           YouGov  Economist        523.0          a   
3  2020-02-02  2020-02-04           YouGov  Economist        599.0          a   
4  2020-02-07  2020-02-09  Morning Consult        NaN       2200.0          a   


excel_doc = ['Monmouth University' 'Selzer & Co.' 'ABC News/The Washington Post'
 'Siena College/The New York Times Upshot' 'YouGov']
```

El código que he escrito es

```
approval_polls = approval_polls[approval_polls['pollster'].isin(excel_doc)]
```

A priori esto debería ser válido, verdad?

Me encuentro que el resultado es:

```
print (approval_polls)

[start_date, end_date, pollster, sponsor, sample_size, population, ...]
```

El resultado que esperaba, sería algo así:

```
print(approval_polls.head(5))

 start_date    end_date         pollster    sponsor  sample_size population  \
0  2020-02-02  2020-02-04           YouGov  Economist       1500.0          a   
1  2020-02-02  2020-02-04           YouGov  Economist        376.0          a   
2  2020-02-02  2020-02-04           YouGov  Economist        523.0          a   
3  2020-02-02  2020-02-04           YouGov  Economist        599.0          a
```

Alguien me puede decir por qué sucede esto?
Muchas gracias.

Comment: lo que quieres hacer es comparar los datos de la columna `pollster` y saber si se encuentran en la lista `excel_doc` y que te regrese los que coinciden, no?

Comment: Tu lista `excel_doc` está bien como la pegaste? Cada elemento debe estar separado por una coma, o sino Python te va a juntarlo todo en una cadena

Comment: @Christian, que me regrese toda la fila del dataframe en caso de que el valor de la columna del dataframe y de los valores del excel coincidan, correcto

Comment: @DannyTalent, puede ser que ahí esté el fallo? El excel era otro dataframe, he seleccionado una única columna y he eliminado los valores repetidos usando ```unique()```

Comment: @icatalan lamento decir que ese no es el fallo, ya estoy haciendo una respuesta

Comment: Adelante, a mi me funcionó reformateando la lista para que sea de formato `["a","b","c"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que al utilizar `df.isin(value)` esto retorna un DataFrame de boleanos, mas no retorna los que coinciden, para lograr esto nos podemos ayuda de un filtro basico de pandas.
Un error que tambien tienes es en la lista, pues no esta separada por comas (`,`), por lo cual deberia quedar asi:

```py
excel_doc = ['Monmouth University','Selzer & Co.','ABC News/The Washington Post','Siena College/The New York Times Upshot','YouGov']
```

En tu comentario dices que usas `list()` para convertir a una lista, pero esta mal pues si hacemos eso.

```py
excel_doc = ['Monmouth University' 'Selzer & Co.' 'ABC News/The Washington Post'
 'Siena College/The New York Times Upshot' 'YouGov']

excel_doc = list(excel_doc)
print(excel_doc)
```

Obtenemos como resultado

```
['Monmouth UniversitySelzer & Co.ABC News/The Washington PostSiena College/The New York Times UpshotYouGov']
```

Lo cual hara que al aplicar nuestro filtro no coincida con nada. Es mejor que lo separes por comas o hagas un ciclo for para convertirlo a una lista correctamenete

---

Para solucionar tu problema podemos utilizar la funcion `.apply()` de pandas para aplicar una condicion

```py
approval_polls = df["pollster"].apply(lambda x: x in excel_doc )
```

Bueno esto nos dará como resultado lo mismo que `isin()`, nos retorna valores boleanos, para eso solo lo metemos en un df para que retorne los elementos que coinciden.

```py
approval_polls = df[df["pollster"].apply(lambda x: x in excel_doc )]
```

Y listo, tendremos como resultado un DataFrame con los resultados que coincidan

```
   start_date    end_date pollster    sponsor  sample_size population
0  2020-02-02  2020-02-04   YouGov  Economist       1500.0       a
1  2020-02-02  2020-02-04   YouGov  Economist        376.0       a
2  2020-02-02  2020-02-04   YouGov  Economist        523.0       a
3  2020-02-02  2020-02-04   YouGov  Economist        599.0       a
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Para convertir a una lista, simplemente hago ```list (excel_doc)```, correcto?  Al ejecutar de nuevo la función, me devuelve un dataframe vacío

Comment: que raro a mi si me devuelve los datos

Comment: Edite mi respuesta, ahi explico cual es tu error

Comment: muchas gracias. Ahora tengo que ver cómo hacer la separación por comas correctamente!

Comment: Si deseas puedes hacer otra pregunta, detallando como obtienes esos resultados y especificando cual es el resultado que deseas obtener